# Converting strtotime to an integer

Tags: php

I am trying to get the time -24 hours ago using this:

```
$a = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))));
$a = strtotime($a);
```

which calculates fine, but when I use the variable `$a` to send to an API, it says that the value is not an integer. The error returned is:

`400 Invalid 'Query' parameter: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field SearchClause.ClauseChildren.RuleValue of type string`

If I change the variable to this: `$a = '1583751712';` and send it to the API, it works absolutely fine.

Comment: If I understood the error properly the API isn't expecting a numerical value but a String, thus $a as string works.

Comment: [https://3v4l.org/EZMB1](https://3v4l.org/EZMB1)

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need all that code. All you need here is `$a = strtotime('-1 day');`. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because your `API` requires a `string` and not an `integer`. The function `strtotime` returns the `timestamp as integer`. Try to `typecast` your integer to a string. Like `Sherif` wrote before, you don't need the date formatting if you only need to return your timestamp.

```
$a = (string) strtotime('-1 day');
```